# Copying JSON data from dynamoDB to redshift

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift

I wonder if it's possible to copy data from dynamoDB to redshift if my dynamoDB data contains JSON format values. If yes, how is it going to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload values from DynamoDB to s3 then you can you copy commands to load data back to redshift.

The redshift supports JSON structure to be copied into DB .
Refer link : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html

Comment: Is it necessary to go through S3 ?

Comment: you can load data directly into redshift by using link below. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading-data-from-dynamodb.html . but if you wish to convert json data into column then you need , it not directly possible

Comment: I wonder why ... I thought that redshift uses postgresql which supports JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can *now* move data into amazon redshift from DynamoDB using COPY

1. assumes that the table is already created in redshift
2. dynamoDB does not have a concept of NULL as in SQL. You will have define in redshift how to interpret blanks
3. you need to make sure that the redshift data type "accomodates" the data type coming from DynamoDB

Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/RedshiftforDynamoDB.html

```
copy <redshift_tablename> from 'dynamodb://<table_name>'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access_key_id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret_access_key>'
readratio <ratio>;
```

- ratio is the percentage of throughput (0-100) that you are willing to assign for the copy. ideally this number should be lower than your average unused throughput