Handling nested fields in Amazon Redshift using COPY command when loading from dynamo db source
I am trying to load data into Redshift from a DynamoDB table. The table includes nested fields which does not get fetched correctly. The data inside the DynamoDB has structure like
"Status": {
    "S": "queued"
  },
"optional": {
    "M": {
      "file_size": {
        "N": "1.884"
      },
      "records_count": {
        "N": "1276"
      },
      "submission_timestamp": {
        "N": "1716764400"
      }
    }
  },
}

Inside Redshift I have tried two solutions one is to create a table like
CREATE TABLE my_redshift_table (
    status VARCHAR(50)
    optional_file_size DECIMAL(10,4),
    optional_records_count BIGINT,
    optional_submission_timestamp BIGINT,
);

But then the data inside the columns is NULL
The other option is trying to have optional as SUPER like this
CREATE TABLE my_redshift_table (
    status VARCHAR(50)
    optional SUPER,
);

But from my understanding the datatype SUPER is not valid as it throws error and reading documentation the types that is supported are either STRING or NUMBER.
Is there any good way of handling the nested fields? I do not want to perform an ETL process by flattening the data and store in S3, it needs to be queried or loaded directly from DynamoDB into Redshift.
Error message when using datatype SUPER
ERROR: Unsupported Data Type: Current Version only supports Strings and Numbers Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: Unsupported Data Type: Current Version only supports Strings and Numbers code: 9005 context: Table Name = ddp-dev-euwest1-bookkeeper-v2 query: 6301675[child_sequence:1] location: copy_dynamodb_scanner.cpp:182 process: query0_4084_6301676 [pid=27935] ----------------------------------------------- [ErrorId: 1-6737121e-20350b656e58fdf1669a5df6]


Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267289. Maybe zero-etl will work? If not just dump to s3 first then ingest from s3

You can create the target table as follows:
CREATE TABLE my_redshift_table (
    status VARCHAR(50),
    optional VARCHAR(MAX)
);

and then query it (and/or create a view):
SELECT 
    status,
    json_extract_path_text(optional, 'file_size')::DECIMAL(10, 4) AS optional_file_size,
    json_extract_path_text(optional, 'records_count')::BIGINT AS optional_records_count,
    json_extract_path_text(optional, 'submission_timestamp')::BIGINT AS optional_submission_timestamp
FROM my_redshift_table;

In Redshift, VARCHAR(MAX) data type is 65535

I've now tried this solution but I forgot to mention that the data inside dynamodb is maped, the structure is this:
"optional": {
"M": {
"file_size": {
"N": "8.638"
},
"records_count": {
"N": "8853"
},
"submission_timestamp": {
"N": "1721710800"
}
}
},
Throws error unsupported datatype as optional is of "M", any way to handle this directly?
